# Animating with Geometry Nodes with a real life time line

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I'm creating a reconstruction using real life data. I've imported a spreadsheet that has a very long list of rows that I've converted to a curve with the intention of animating an object along that curve. The spreadsheet contains x,y,z coordinates. I also have a column for frameNumber or time (t). All the data for the animation is brought to animation nodes using the Named Attribute node.

So the object needs to be at the xyz coordinate at frame number 't'. Is this possible in geometry node animation or am I a crazy person?

[image]

Comment: Instead of a curve, could you have a "Mesh Line" with the vertices index matching the "frameNumber" ? If so, you could use a "Sample Index" node to recover (X,Y,Z) selecting the right frame by connecting the "Index" input socket to the "Frame" output socket of a "Scene Time" node. Otherwise, the curve enables smooth interpolation with a "Sample Curve" node, but you will have to convert your "frameNumber" to U coordinate going from 0 to 1 to input in the "Factor" socket to "move" along the curve as the frame number increases.

Comment: In your initial spreadsheet file, is time/frames uniformly sampled, with a constant interval ? If so, you can save you Geometry Nodes by just having an empty following the curve with the "Follow Path" modifier.

Comment: No, not constant. I have created the frameNumber from the time. 0 being the first point, and every frame being a second referencing that... eg 3.34:55 is frame 0 and 3.35:08 is 12 (13 seconds apart). But open to other ways...

Comment: Could you share your Blender file with the spreadsheet data already imported, using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? It will be easier for us to help you.